# cuFFT don't see what my kernel did

Tags: cuda

I have a very strange issue using cuFFT. I tried to prepare my input data with a kernel that apply a Hanning window. Everything seems fine. here the issue: cuFFT run on the data WITHOUT the hanning window applied. I don't understand why.

I tried the following:
test1:
- I run the kernel to apply window
- get back the data to the host and check the values: all is OK. the window is applied
- copy back the values to the device
- run the fft: no luck, it eat non windowed data!

test2:
- I don't use a kernel, I apply the window with CPU
- I run the fft: it works. it eat the windowed data

Is there any rational explanation to this? 
Is there some kind of cache involved here ?

NOTE: I use the same device memory pointer in my kernel and in cuFFT

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It appears that I ran my kernel **applyWindow** only on the first 512 samples of my data. This explain why it did nothing. Running the kernel with the right settings did the job on the entire buffer.

```
int nbBlock = inputSizeInSamples / deviceProp.maxThreadsPerBlock;
applyWindow <<<nbBlock, deviceProp.maxThreadsPerBlock >>>( ... )
```